# VSCode intellisense not working for one c# project under the solution

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have  just installed VS Code on my Mac and installed OmniSharp to work with dotnet Core and C# applications. I did get code from GitHub, which used to have no issues. However it is having following issues right now:

1. I have multiple projects in a solution
2. Dotnet build from solution does not show any errors on one particular project. However, if I go to the folder containing the problem project and then do `dotnet build` on that particular project then it does actually show errors. Before this problem, doing doenet build at solution level will show me all the errors in all the projects including this one.
3. Also, when I am looking at the file which does have issues, the code whcih clearly have isssues, does not show any red-lines under it.
4. Intellisense also stopped working. In any file of this particular project I cannot go to any item > Right click and go to definition. It just does not work anymore.

I have tried deleting bin and obj folders and rebuilding the project but it does not seem to be working. Anything else that I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this project is included in sln file. VS Code is folder based, so it show this project with files as directory, but OmniSharp will not recognize it. You can also check OmniSharp logs (in VS Code -> Output -> C#/Omnisharp (I dont remember which one)) if this project is loaded without any errors

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution (after hours of searching) on another question here with a similar problem with regards to Xunit classes not being recognised by intellisense.

You need to ensure that Omnisharp has the solution file selected (.sln) containing the projects, rather than an individual project .csproj file.

Once I selected the solution file, then hey presto, intellisense works!

type (in VS Code):
ctrl + shift + P
type "Omnisharp:Select Project"
and select your solution file NOT the project file!

Hope this helps, I personally am mighty relieved!

Answer (score 1):

If your intellisense (VS CODE)  not  showing build error while typing.
Do things.
Step 1: Install Extension C#.
If you already completed Step 1.
Step 2: Go to Setting > Extensions > c# Configuration > Omnisharp:Disable MSBuild Diagnostic Warning.  This must be checked.